# Implement a function that takes 2 integers and returns the sum of every number between(and including) them

Tags: javascript

I'm currently doing the ODIN project. One of the tests is to write a function that takes two numbers and returns the sum of every number between and including them.

The function is to return the sum if both arguments are above 0. If one of the arguments is below 0 or not a number it should return 'ERROR'.

I have got it working if both arguments are integers but not for the other two parameters.

I know i've probably overcomplicated my code and there is probably a simple solution but am looking for a similar solution to mine and also a more refined version if possible.

Code is:

```
const sumAll = function(a, b) {
let min = Math.min(a, b)
let max = Math.max(a, b)
let range = []
let sum = 0

for (let i = min; i<= max; i++) {
  range.push(i)
}

for (let j = 0; j <= range.length; j++) {
  if (j < 0 || typeof j != "number") {
    sum = 'ERROR'
  }else
  sum = sum + j
}

};
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check whether the parameter is a number or not. An object that is not an integer will return `true`.

---

Your code will never return `'ERROR'` if the parameter is smaller than 0. This:

```js
if (j < 0 || typeof j != "number") {
    sum = 'ERROR'
}else
```

will never cause `sum` to be `'ERROR'` since `j` will never be smaller than `0` as its initialization value is `0`. Even if it did, you would have to add a `break`, otherwise `j` would be concatenated later in the `for` loop (`sum = sum + j`) once it no longer satisfied the condition (in the `else` clause).

You also don't need the `range` array at all. Just use one `for` loop to iterate from `min` to `max` and add to `sum` instead of pushing the numbers all to an array, then looping over it and adding it to `sum`.

Final result:

```js
const sumAll = function(a, b) {
  if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) return 'ERROR';
  if(a < 0 || b < 0) return 'ERROR'
  let min = Math.min(a, b)
  let max = Math.max(a, b)
  let sum = 0
  for (let j = min; j < max; j++) //can be shortened to: for(; min < max; min++)
      sum = sum + j
  return sum;
};

console.log(sumAll('Hello', 'World!'));
console.log(sumAll(1, 10));
console.log(sumAll(-1, -1));
```

Comment: You don't need a for loop at all, look at my solution.

Comment: @sidc *"I know i've probably overcomplicated my code and there is probably a simple solution but **am looking for a similar solution to mine**"*

Comment: Oh, well just put the answer out there if anyone else wants to use a more efficient version.

Comment: Ahhh thank you. This answer has taught me loads. I did try the isNaN but couldn't get that working either. I knew there was a simpler solution. At least my thinking wasn't a million miles away from getting a working solution. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @AaronAlley No problem. Glad to help :)

Comment: Just to add a little bit more. There is a bit of an edge case where if a number was put inside a string e.g "90" it would get interpreted as a number and would not return error. I solved this by adding || typeof a == "string" || typeof b == "string" to the first if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without a for loop with simple math. The sum of a series is equal to the `(end + start)(num elements)/2`. For this problem, that would be `(Math.abs(a-b) + 1)(a + b)/2`.

So your answer would be:

```js
const sumAll = function(a, b) {
  if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) return 'ERROR';
  if(a < 0 || b < 0) return 'ERROR'
  return (Math.abs(a-b) + 1)*(a + b)/2;
};
```

Comment: the formula is wrong. It should be `a(a+1)/2 - b(b+1)/2`

Comment: Also thank you. I knew there would be a relatively simple solution I just didnt know how to get there. I did initially go with a similar maths formula earlier but couldnt figure out a way to solve the other parts. Again appreciate the help.

Comment: @naveen fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```js
const sumAll = function(a, b, range=[]) {
  
  if (a < 0 || b < 0) return 'ERROR'
  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) return 'ERROR'
 
  for (let i = Math.min(a,b); i<= Math.max(a,b); i++) {
    range.push(i)
  }
  
  return range.reduce((a,b) => a+b)
  
}

console.log(sumAll(1,10));
console.log(sumAll(10,1));
console.log(sumAll(-10,1));
console.log(sumAll(1,-10));
console.log(sumAll(1,'a'));
console.log(sumAll('a',1));
console.log(sumAll('a',-1));
```